# Why Wont My Filtered Array Results (Re-)Render On Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?

I'm *desperately* trying to get my jquery carousel to re-render with the results of a filtered array - but really hitting issues today.

I grab the carouselId from its div with `wrapper`
i get the api array of objects & store it in moviesArray.

Then the key thing is that when someone has typed in the input, it re-renders the carousel based on that newly filtered array.

```
function populateCarousel() {
  var moviesArray = [];
  var tempResultsArr = [];

  fetch('http://localhost:3000/getdata')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      moviesArray = json;

// ===== if NO searchTerm is entered ====
// THIS ONE WORKS

      if (typeof searchTerm === 'undefined') {
        moviesArray.map((each) => {

          var eachTile = document.createElement("a");
          var imageForEachTile = document.createElement("img");
          imageForEachTile.setAttribute('src', each.poster);
          eachTile.setAttribute("class", "carousel-item thumbnail-item");
          eachTile.setAttribute("href", "#linkToSomeWhere");
          eachTile.innerHTML = each.title;
          eachTile.appendChild(imageForEachTile);
          wrapper.appendChild(eachTile);
        })

      } else {


        // ===== if a searchTerm *IS* entered ====
        // THIS ONE DOESN'T WORK!
          while (wrapper.firstChild) {
              wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild);
          }

          function checkWords(searchTerm, arr) {
              let st = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
              return arr.filter(each => each.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(st) === 0);
          }

          let newArr = checkWords(searchTerm, moviesArray);

          newArr.map((each) => {
            var eachTile = document.createElement("a");
            var imageForEachTile = document.createElement("img");
            imageForEachTile.setAttribute('src', each.poster);
            eachTile.setAttribute("class", "carousel-item thumbnail-item");
            eachTile.setAttribute("href", "#linkToSomeWhere");
            eachTile.innerHTML = each.title;
            eachTile.appendChild(imageForEachTile);
            wrapper.appendChild(eachTile);
          })

          // this logs out correctly & when i go into the html
          // the correct searchresults are there, a and img tags.
          // but they dont show.
          console.log('wrapper: ', wrapper);
      }
    })
}
```

you notice the .map((each)... is identical on both sides of the IF/ELSE.

It does create the elements and attributes correctly, and does append them because a) i can log them out but b) i can actually inspect the HTMl in chrome and see them there.

But why aren't they actually showing?

Comment: I guess it's a CSS issue. Your HTML is there but is invisible... What if you comment out  `while (wrapper.firstChild) { wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.firstChild); }`  ?  If you are just removing everything from `wrapper`, maybe you could rewrite it as `wrapper.html (''); ` ? I guess that is the only difference between the 2 IF/ELSE branches.

Comment: @gregn3 thanks dude - i've noticed css is pulling through a `display: none` from the materialize.min.css library but no idea why. 
When i showed a colleague at work this sort of thing before he moved the code out or inside of a fetch & it worked. Nothing i'm trying today is working though. :(